# Amplitude spectrum change after altering phases of Fourier coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, random, fft

I'm trying to generate some random 1d sequences (`r`) by changing the phases of the Fourier coefficients of a given array (`y`). I assume the amplitude spectrum of these two sequences (`y` and `r`) won't change after doing this, and they indeed don't if I use `numpy.fft.fft()`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft

n=512
x=np.linspace(0,10*np.pi,n)
y=np.sin(x)+2*np.sin(2*x)+2*np.sin(5*x)

#-------------Get Fourier coefficients-------------
cf1=fft.fft(y)
amp1=np.abs(cf1)
theta1=np.angle(cf1)

#-Randomly alter phase keeping amplitude unchanged-
theta2=np.random.normal(0,1.,size=theta1.shape)+theta1
cf2=amp1*np.cos(theta2)+1j*amp1*np.sin(theta2)

#-----------------------IFFT-----------------------
y2=fft.ifft(cf2)

#------------Compare amplitude spectrum------------
cf3=fft.fft(y2)
amp2=np.abs(cf3)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure=plt.figure()
ax=figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(amp1-amp2,'k-')

plt.show(block=False)
```

The resultant plot is a random sequence at the order of 1e-13. So effectively unchanged.

But I'm interested in generating random real data rather than complex. Using `numpy.fft.rfft()` and `numpy.fft.irfft()` instead, the amplitudes agree at all frequencies but the last one (`amp1[-1]` and `amp2[-1]`), and the difference is at the order of 0.1. According to the docs this correspondes to the Nyquist frequency, and the difference doesn't go away if the data size is an odd number. I don't understand what is causing the difference or how should I generate a real valued array with identical amplitude spectrum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the (single) "Nyquist bin" of the `rfft` is the problem, it looks like you shouldn't change its phase under the assumption that `rfft` uses:

> When the input is purely real, its transform is Hermitian, i.e., the component at frequency f_k is the complex conjugate of the component at frequency -f_k, which means that for real inputs there is no information in the negative frequency components that is not already available from the positive frequency components. The family of rfft functions is designed to operate on real inputs, and exploits this symmetry by computing only the positive frequency components, up to and including the Nyquist frequency. Thus, n input points produce n/2+1 complex output points. The inverses of this family assumes the same symmetry of its input, and for an output of n points uses n/2+1 input points.

plot looks good when I patch the last last rfft bin to keep original phase

```
cf1=fft.rfft(y)
amp1=np.abs(cf1)
theta1=np.angle(cf1)
tlast=theta1[-1] # quick patch, save last (Nyquist) phase
#-Randomly alter phase keeping amplitude unchanged-
theta2=np.random.normal(0,1.,size=theta1.shape)+theta1
theta2[-1] = tlast # restore Nyquist bin original phase
cf2=amp1*np.cos(theta2)+1j*amp1*np.sin(theta2)
```

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Previously I manually removed the imaginary part of the last bin, and forgot that the real part has also been changed. And the reason that odd-numbered array doesn't match is that by default `np.fft.irfft()` returns an output with length of `2*(m-1)` therefore always an even number. I've to explicitly give it a second argument to force the output size to the original size: `np.fft.irfft(cf2,len(y))`.

Comment: Alternatively, one could still use `fft()` but randomly perturb the positive or negative part of the frequency domain and mirror that perturbation to the other half. Again left the Nyquist frequency unchanged for even-sized input. Then the IFFT output is the desired real-valued random sequence with identical power spectrum.